# Where is Rubinius' Actor API?

Tags: actor, rubinius

I got the following output from `pry` when trying out the example from http://rubini.us/doc/en/systems/concurrency/ with Rubinius 2.2.9:

```
2.1.0 (main):0 > RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.1.0"
2.1.0 (main):0 > RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
=> 0
2.1.0 (main):0 > RUBY_PLATFORM
=> "x86_64-darwin13.2.0"
2.1.0 (main):0 > RUBY_ENGINE
=> "rbx"
2.1.0 (main):0 > require 'actor'
LoadError: no such file to load -- actor
from kernel/common/code_loader.rb:441:in `load_error'
```

Is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is slightly outdated.

Commit [79bd4c30](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/commit/79bd4c3021aa1ffd18064d26dd4b7e48aed4ab66) appears to remove the Actor api from the Rubinius standard library and extract it into the [rubinius-actor](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-actor) gem. As far as I can tell with a quick glance, it's the exact same API as the documentation describes.